# Prevent Excel truncating leading zeros for HYPERLINKS

Tags: excel, hyperlink

Please note this question is for hyperlinks so do not mark it as duplicate without actually looking at the problem. I know we can prevent excel from truncating leading zeros by setting the cell format to text. That works. However, when I add a hyperlink and in its text to display I add a value like 00111, the hyperlink name is truncated.

Is there any way to prevent that?

[image]

Comment: is your number a set number of digits long?  ie it will always be 6 characters?

Comment: @ForwardEd no its not fixed. I am getting data from a server, and the data may or may not contain leading zeros and can have variable length. In any case I want to present the data as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of formatting the cell as TEXT, how about turning the number into text first and then turning it into a hyper link.